# Default color of preferredBarTintColor?

Tags: swift, themes

I would like to know a default color of this (white?) frame in `SFSafariViewController`.
Im able to change a color with:

```swift
let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: URL)
safariViewController.preferredBarTintColor = UIColor.white
```

[image: Frame here]

But I think its not clear white.

I would like to preserve this "white" color in dark mode, so trying to set it in my code.

Comment: Did you try with systemBackground color.?

Comment: I do not understand why Apple does not respect selected color and modifies it. And it is not mentioned in doc.